# Line a label and boxview next to side by side

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Gently, how can I achieve this in xaml? It must be pretty damn easy but can't wrap my mind around it :/
This is what I'm trying to achieve : [image]

This is my view.xaml

```
<StackLayout  x:Name="stackExample">
    <StackLayout  Margin="10,10,10,5" >
       <Label Text="Info" />
       <BoxView Color="#29abe2" WidthRequest ="100" HeightRequest="1" />
    </StackLayout>



   <StackLayout x:Name="optionsContentStack"  >

   </StackLayout>
</StackLayout>
```

this is my view.xaml.cs

```
 foreach (var ex in example)
  {
  var labelHtmlInst = new Label { Text = ex.Info, FontSize = 15, TextColor = Color.FromHex("#222222"), HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center, VerticalOptions=LayoutOptions.Center, HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Start };
  optionsContentStack.Children.Add(labelHtmlInst);

  var labelDs = new Label { Text = ex.Info, FontSize = 10, TextColor = Color.FromHex("#999999"), HorizontalOptions=LayoutOptions.Start, HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Start, Margin = new Thickness(0, 0, 0, 10) };
  optionsContentStack.Children.Add(labelDs);

  var boxviewDs = new BoxView { Color = Color.FromHex("#f7931e"), WidthRequest = 100, HeightRequest = 1, HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Start };
  optionsContentStack.Children.Add(boxviewDs);
  }
```

Comment: Set the Orientation of the StackLayout that contains the line and label as "Horizontal". And also Label's and Line's Padding and Margin as 0. Although you might need to write a custom Label renderer to remove Label's "inner Paddings".

Comment: if you check my code carefully you can see that I have two labels. One in top `Lorem Ipsum` and than is the other one which should come along with the lilne `more`. I can't achieve it the way you sad it  :/ @Vahid

Comment: Did you try using [GridLayout](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/user_interface/layouts/grid-layout/) ?

Comment: So you've two labels: labelHtmlInst and labelDs. Which one you wanna be placed along with boxviewDs?

Comment: BTW, if there are several "examples", why don't you use a ListView?